# 2018 Winter Bash Leaderboard

Tags: discussion, events, stackexchange

For all those interested in the Winter Bash hats, there is a leaderboard for hats earned on just the Arduino Stack Exchange website.

https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/arduino.stackexchange.com

A list of hats is available here:

https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/

And to round it all off, here is a link to where Arduino SE ranks compared to other SE sites:

https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard

Winterbash2018 discussions:
[Winter Bash 2018 Hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319838/winter-bash-2018-hat-list)
[Show off your hats! (2018 edition)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320014/show-off-your-hats-2018-edition)
[Winter Bash 2018 Knitting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319846/winter-bash-2018-knitting) Yes, you can do some knitting too!

**I would like to hear what hats you think are easiest to achieve!!**

Answer (score -1):

[image: Top(bar) Hat]

> post a question that gets answered or earn reputation with an answer you post